# Opamp gain seems too high in dc servo circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, troubleshooting

Hi I’m rather new at troubleshooting TI TL074CD oapamps. I have an amplifier with left and right channels that have independent dc servos. I’ve tripled checked the connected component values, and cannot find any shorts. The apparent issue is the near 1000x gain from pin 6 to pin 7 in the right channel dc servo vs a 60x gain in the right channel. Im wondering if the opamps is defective or counterfeit, however this is the second one in a row that I bought from Mouser.com

U1 is left channel opamp
U101 is right channel opamp

I hope I’m totally missing something here, or need more information. Any help is appreciated.

U1(1) 13-18mV ; U101(1)77-85mV
U1(2) .3-.4mV ; U101(2) .43mV
U1(6) .46mV ; U101(6) 10mV
U1(7) 38-40mV ; U101(7) 14084-14088mV
U1(8 and 9) .63-.66mV; U101(8 and 9) 6-9mV
U1(10) .08mV ; U101(10) 11-13mV
U1(13) 2.89mV ; U101(13) 5.00mV
U1(14) 14-16mV; U101(14) 80-82mV

[image: Left Channel DC Servo with voltage readings]

[image: Right Channel DC Servo with voltage readings]

[image: PCB Board Left Channel DC Servo]

[image: PCB Board Right Channel DC Servo]

Comment: Did you swap the opamp already? 43mV on pin 2 indicates that it's most likely defective. This does happen, although very rarely. Also, could you show a picture of your PCB and especially of your grounding?

Comment: How are the op amps powered?

Comment: Sorry for the left right typo. Opamps are powered by the circuit attached. Yes swapped opamps in right channel only. This is the second one from mouser.com, all voltages read the same.

Comment: Will send the photo of pcb after I’ve compressed it. Thanks for the responses! What about the gain from U101(6) 10mV to U101(7) 14V. Does that indicate a defect? Aren’t gains calculated by the circuit’s resistance values, which are the same in both dc servos.

Comment: That's not gain -  its saturation at the positive rail

Comment: That opamp is set up as a comparator, so you’d expect hi gain as there is no feedback. Looks like there might be some hysteresis so what happens is very dependant on the voltage at the cathodes of D6/7.

Comment: Check polarity and functionality of D17.

Comment: I’ve also replaced D117, D106, and D107, and verified the cathode is facing the correct direction. I’m using the working Left dc servo as a visual reference as well. I’ve double checked no shorts especially to the +\- 15 voltage rails. I measured resistance across U0101(4) and U101(7) ~4.7MOhm. What does saturation at the positive rail mean? Is the circuit and opamp working as designed then? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I’ve uploaded photos of the PCBs.

Comment: I've uploaded visuals of the voltages on the dc servo. I think I'm gathering this is expected by design, correct? I'm not sure if I swapping out another tl074 will do any good. I'm in the dark here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I should clarify- I think the right channel dc servo that uses U101 is not working as designed and a component or components are failing. Or the dc servo is working per design according to the voltage readings.

Comment: Also the left channel dc offset is stable at .8 +/- .02mV, while the right channel dc offset is 10-20mV. Is this just how a dc servo should be working, and there’s going to be this type of variation? Or could there be something wrong with one of the components, in which case the only one I don’t have a test bench to test U101 (TL074CD).

Comment: Just realized there's a decent chance those diodes are actually zener diodes. I think I accidentlally mixed ll4148 with bzt55c15 or bzt55c10. I've ordered a fresh batch of ll4148 and will follow up after I've installed those.

Comment: @Kartman -- not quite a comparator, but a saturating integrator.    Ends in the same place, but most comparators don't slow down the transitions.

Comment: @Scott Seidman - my interpretation of the circuit is an integrator followed by a unity inverting stage. D6/7 go into a comparator stage to detect if the integrator has swung too far pos or neg. for all we know the circuit could be working fine but the problem is elsewhere. How many times have I been caught in that trap!

Comment: Deleted my answer. I think I’ve narrowed down my issue to two questions: 1.) Is the right channel dc servo working as designed based on the voltage measurements I’ve provided? 2.) It seems running a simulation is one method to finding faults. Am I correct in using two inputs for the simulation, at U101(1) and U101(13)?